# Sort a hash of arrays by one of the arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

In Ruby, is there a short and sweet way to sort this hash of arrays by score descending:

```
scored = {:id=>[1, 2, 3], :score=>[8.3, 5, 10]}
```

so it looks like this?:

```
scored = {:id=>[3, 1, 2], :score=>[10, 8.3, 5]}
```

I couldnt find an example where I can sort arrays within a hash like this? I could do this with some nasty code but I feel like there should be a 1 or 2 liner that does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sort_by`

```
scored = {:id=>[1, 2, 3], :score=>[8.3, 5, 10]}

scored.tap do |s| 
  s[:id] = s[:id].sort_by.with_index{ |a, i| -s[:score][i] }
  s[:score] = s[:score].sort_by{ |a| -a }
end
#=> {:id=>[3, 1, 2], :score=>[10, 8.3, 5]}
```

Comment: Went with this one as I felt it was slightly more communicative. Thanks for this.

Comment: Agree with readability. The overhead of making two `sort_by` calls will be negligible in all cases, and also there's no need to allocate additional arrays, as in my answer. The only (highly theoretical) concurrency issue is that if you mutate one score in between sort calls (which will never happen real life, of course), you are screwed. :-) This is probably the best answer.

Comment: @Drenmi, I disagree. We should not sort twice when we can sort once. If the value arrays were sufficiently large, methods that sort once would be noticeably more efficiency. Moreover, sorting twice, imo, adversely affects readability. Sorry, fl00r, but I don't consider this answer to be up to your usual high standard.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you shamed me :). And your solution is much better, it should be accepted (cc @joshweir)

Answer (score 2):

```
order = scored[:score].each_with_index.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last).reverse
  #=> [2,0,1]
scored.update(scored) { |_,a| a.values_at *order }
  #=> {:id=>[3, 1, 2], :score=>[10, 8.3, 5]}
```

If `scored` is to not to be mutated, replace `update` with `merge`.

Some points:

- Computing `order` makes it easy for the reader to understand what's going on.
- The second line uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged (which here is all keys). This is a convenient way to modify hash values (generally), in part because the new hash is returned.
- I sorted then reversed, rather than sorted by negated values, to make the method more rubust. (That is, the elements of the arrays that are the values can be from any class that implements `<=>`).
- With Ruby 2.2+, another way to sort an array `arr` in descending order is to use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by): `arr.max_by(arr.size).to_a`.

The first line could be replaced with:

```
arr = scored[:score]
order = arr.each_index.sort_by { |i| arr[i] }.reverse
  #=> [2,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. It has an intermediate step, where it utilizes a zipped version of the `scores` object, but produces the correct output:

```
s = scored.values.inject(&:zip).sort_by(&:last).reverse
#=> [[3, 10], [1, 8.3], [2, 5]]

result = { id: s.map(&:first), score: s.map(&:last) }
#=> { :id => [3, 1, 2], :score => [10, 8.3, 5] }
```